# Updating mmap file with struct in Go

Tags: file, go, struct, updates, mmap

Similar to [Writing struct to mapped memory file (mmap)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337517/writing-struct-to-mapped-memory-file-mmap), how to write a struct to mmap file or update mmap file with struct in Go?

Suppose my binary file begins with a binary header of

```golang
type MVHD struct {
    Version      byte
    Flags        [3]byte
    DateCreated  time.Time
    DateModified time.Time

    TimeUnit        uint32 // time unit per second (default = 600)
    DurationInUnits uint64 // time length (in time units)

    Raw []byte // undecoded data after decoded bits above
}
```

Say I want to map it as memory file and update the `DateModified` field, is that possible?

(my limited reading on mmap in Go is that it can only be accessed via byte array, but I'm sure there is a way to access it via struct. I found one [here](https://gist.github.com/ericjster/eea32820660e26b16174fadd4034dd9d) using `reflect` but it is too complicated for me to grasp the basic idea)

Comment: `struct` layout is machine-dependent; data files often should be machine-*in*dependent (though requirements and thus strategies can differ for some cases).

Comment: Well, IMHO, that's a problem for every single programming language, but since binary files can be read/write fine using `struct` with every single programming language, I believe they can handle mmap using `struct` just as well.

Comment: Screwdrivers *can be* used as chisels just fine. This does not make it a good practice. If you really insist on using Go `struct` here though, take out the slice header; it's not compatible with this.

Comment: You can use `unsafe` to map arbitrary memory to whatever type you want; whether that is a good idea or not I guess is up to you. Why not just write it encoded in some standard way to avoid the pitfalls of unsafe and machine dependent layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`encoding/binary`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary) to read/write fixed size structs. This approach is portable and doesn't depend on the memory layout, compiler, or CPU architecture. Eg:

```
// Note: using uint32 instead of time.Time for decoding.
// Convert to time.Time afterwards if needed.
type MVHD struct {
    Version          byte
    Flags            [3]byte
    DateCreatedSecs  uint32
    DateModifiedSecs uint32

    TimeUnit        uint32 // time unit per second (default = 600)
    DurationInUnits uint64 // time length (in time units)
}

// ..or use binary.BigEndian - whichever is correct for your data.
var endian = binary.LittleEndian

func decode(rd io.Reader) (*MVHD, error) {
    var header MVHD 
    if err := binary.Read(rd, endian, &header); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &header, nil
}
```

Use `bytes.NewReader` to convert a `[]byte` into an `io.Reader`. This will allow you to use `decode` with mmap data.

Alternatively, you can decode it manually:

```golang
func decode2(buf []byte) (*MVHD, error) {
    if len(buf) < 24 {
        return nil, errors.New("not enough data")
    }  
    return &MVHD{
        Version:          buf[0],
        Flags:            [3]byte{buf[1], buf[2], buf[3]},
        DateCreatedSecs:  binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(buf[4:8]),
        DateModifiedSecs: binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(buf[8:12]),
        TimeUnit:         binary.LittleEndian.Uint32(buf[12:16]),
        DurationInUnits:  binary.LittleEndian.Uint64(buf[16:24]),
    }, nil
}
```

Similarly, you can update data in place with [`binary.ByteOrder`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#ByteOrder) `Put` calls:

```golang
func updateDateModified(buf []byte, t uint32) error {
    if len(buf) < 12 {
        return errors.New("not enough data")
    }
    binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(buf[8:12], t)
    return nil
}
```